# How to change element when one of objects in array has status "Confirmed"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{submissions &&
  submissions.files_set.map((el) => {
    if (el.confirmed_status === null) {
      return <ConfirmData />;
    } else if (el.confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED") {
      return <SentData />;
    }
})}
```

I have such structure (placed within JSX context). I need to show `<ConfirmData />` when one element has status `null`. When all elements have status `"CONFIRMED"` I should show `<SentData />`. So how to do this?

---

```
  const submissions = submissionsCopy.map((item, index) => {
    let currentId = false;
    currentElement
      ? (currentId = currentElement.submission_id)
      : (currentId = false);

    return (
      <SubmissionItem
        current={item.submission_id === currentId}
        item={item}
        key={index}
        chooseSubmission={() => {
          handleChooseSubmission(item);
        }}
      />
    );
  });

//subm item

const SubmissionItem = ({ item, current, chooseSubmission }) => {
  const { name, created_at, files_set } = item;

  const d = new Date(created_at);

  var renewalDate =
    d.getDate() +
    "." +
    (d.getMonth() + 1) +
    "." +
    d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);

  const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
    let str = string.toLowerCase();
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  };

  let submissionResult;
  if (files_set) {
    if (files_set.every((el) => el.confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED")) {
      submissionResult = <SentData />;
    } else if (files_set.some((el) => el.confirmed_status === null)) {
      submissionResult = <ConfirmData />;
    } else {
      submissionResult = <ReadyToSend />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper current={current} onClick={chooseSubmission}>
        <SubmissionName>
          <State>{capitalizeFirstLetter(item.type)}</State>
          <Name current={current}>{name}</Name>
          <EffectiveDate current={current}>
            Effective Date : {renewalDate}{" "}
          </EffectiveDate>
        </SubmissionName>
        <StatusArchive>
          <Status>{submissionResult}</Status>
          <Archive current={current}>
            <ArchiveCheckbox type="checkbox" />
          </Archive>
        </StatusArchive>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you want to show `<ConfirmData />`/`<SendData />` once for each element if the criteria are met? Or just once?

Comment: @3limin4t0r just once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you don't want `map`; instead, you want `some` to tell you whether there's an element with `confirmed_status === null` and then you branch on that (with an `if` or a conditional operator).

Using a conditional:

```
{submissions &&
  submissions.files_set.some((el) => el.confirmed_status === null)
  ? <ConfirmData />
  : <SentData />
})}
```

But note that there's a third possibility you haven't accounted for in your question: If none of the elements has `confirmed_status === null` but not all of the elements have `confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED"`.

If you need to double-check for the `confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED"`, you can use `every` for that:

```
{submissions &&
  submissions.files_set.some((el) => el.confirmed_status === null)
  ? <ConfirmData />
  : submissions.files_set.every((el) => el.confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED")
    ? <SentData />
    : <TheOtherThingToShowInTheThirdCase />
})}
```

---

That JSX is getting convoluted enough I'd do it with an `if`/`else if`/`else` prior to the element structure, e.g.:

```javascript
let submissionResult; // Defaults to `undefined`, which won't render anything
if (submissions) {
    if (submissions.files_set.some((el) => el.confirmed_status === null)) {
        submissionResult = <ConfirmData />;
    } else if (submissions.files_set.every((el) => e.confirmed_status === "CONFIRMED")) {
        submissionResult = <SentData />;
    } else {
        submissionResult = <TheOtherThingToShowInTheThirdCase />;
    }
}
```

Then in the element structure, it's just:

```
{submissionResult}
```

Comment: I guess it's good variant, but Idk why in my variant I see `SentData` even only one element is `"CONFIRMED"`

Comment: @VladMovchan - The above isn't a *variant* of what's in  your question, they do different things. You're returning `<ConfirmData />` or `<SentData />` for **each** entry in the array. If there are two entries (one with `null` and the other with `"CONFIRMED"`), you'll return `[<ConfirmData />, <SentData />]` and both will get rendered (along with a warning about missing `key`). The above only returns a single element.

Comment: I need to return only one Element, and this elements depends on the status of  `submissions.files_set`

Comment: @VladMovchan - That's what the above does.

Comment: @VladMovchan - Why? Are you having some problem with the above? What problem? The above renders **one** element for a given array, which is what you've said you want. If it isn't, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating your original problem and an example of the component hierarchy you want in each of the two/three situations. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).